# PHP if condition and foreach inside

Tags: php

I don't understand why my if-condition is not working.

From this html page:

http://www.olympic.org/olympic-results/london-2012/archery

I'm trying to extract information like Olympic edition, trial name etc.
I extract the men's event with this code:

```
$html=file_get_html('http://www.olympic.org/olympic-results/london-2012/archery');


foreach($html->find('div') as $element) {

    if ($element->id == 'gamesSelect')
    {
        $Game =  $element->find('option[selected]', 0)->plaintext . '<br>'; 
    }   

    if ($element->id == 'sportSelect')
    {

        $Sport =  $element->find('option[selected]', 0)->plaintext . '<br>'; 
    }

    if ($element->class == 'man')
    {
        foreach($html->find('span.trial_name') as $e_trial)
        {

          $Event = $e_trial->innertext . '<br>';

        }
    }
}
```

Inside the last if condition I put a foreach loop in order to extract only this text:

> Men's Individual (FITA Olympic Round - 70m) Men's Team (FITA Olympic
>   Round - 70m)

But actually I get all four trial events:

> Men's Individual (FITA Olympic Round - 70m) Men's Team (FITA Olympic
>   Round - 70m) Women's Individual (FITA Olympic Round - 70m) Women's
>   Team (FITA Olympic Round - 70m)

Why this behaviour? I don't understand, since there is the if condition only for men. How can I fix this?

Comment: Shouldn't you be searching `element` instead of `html`?

Comment: That's correct @RST. instead of foreach($html->find('span.trial_name') as $e_trial) try and use foreach($element->find('span.trial_name') as $e_trial)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$html=str_get_html(file_get_html('http://www.olympic.org/olympic-results/london-2012/archery'));


    foreach($html->find('div') as $element) {

        if ($element->id == 'gamesSelect')
        {
            $Game =  $element->find('option[selected]', 0)->plaintext . '<br>';
        }

        if ($element->id == 'sportSelect')
        {

            $Sport =  $element->find('option[selected]', 0)->plaintext . '<br>';
        }

        if ($element->class == 'man')
        {
           foreach($element->find('span.trial_name') as $e_trial)
            {

              $Event = $e_trial->innertext . '<br>';

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after solved I went on with my script adding this code:

$html=file_get_html('http://www.olympic.org/olympic-results/london-2012/archery');

foreach($html->find('div') as $element) {

```
if ($element->id == 'gamesSelect')
{
    $Game =  $element->find('option[selected]', 0)->plaintext . '<br>'; 
}   

if ($element->id == 'sportSelect')
{

    $Sport =  $element->find('option[selected]', 0)->plaintext . '<br>'; 
}

if ($element->class == 'man')
{
    foreach($element->find('span.trial_name') as $e_trial)
    {

      $Event = $e_trial->innertext . '<br>';

       if ($element->class == "medals gold")
       {

           foreach($element->find('td.name') as $e_name)
           {
               $Name = $e_name->innertext . '<br>';
               echo $Name;
           }
       }  


    }
}
```

}

I don't understand how to let it in in the last if condition. Is it not the same of the other if ($element->class == 'man')?