# web scraping content within <div> tag and <td> tag

Tags: web, screen-scraping

I need to scrape data from http://www.hegnar.no/netfonds/aksjekurser/ this link. Actually i want to scrape data from the table of this link. But the code of the table is written within div tag. I used php regex and file_get_content I couldn't scrape it can you help me with the script.

```
<?php

$html = file_get_contents("http://www.hegnar.no/netfonds/aksjekurser");


preg_match_all(
            '<tr>
<td class="left"><a href=".*?">(.*?)<\/a><\/td>.*?
<td class="left">(.*?)<\/td>.*?
<td name=".*?">(.*?)<\/td>.*?
<td name=".*?">(.*?)<\/td>.*?
<td>(.*?)<\/td>.*?
<td class="up" name=".*?">(.*?)<\/td>.*?
<td class="up" name=".*?">(.*?)<\/td>.*?
<td>(.*?)<\/td>.*?
<td>(>*?)<\/td>.*?
<td>(.*?)<\/td>.*?
<td>(.*?)<\/td>.*?
<td name=".*?">(.*?)<\/td>
<td name=".*?">(.*?)<\/td><\/tr>/s',


$html,
$posts, // will contain the article data
PREG_SET_ORDER // formats data into an array of posts
);

foreach ($posts as $post) {
$selskap = $post[1];
$ticket = $post[2];
$siste = $post[3];
$kejop = $post[4];
$slag = $post[5];
$ending = $post[6];
$ending2 = $post[7];
$apring = $post[8];
$lav = $post[9];
$hoy = $post[10];
$forrige = $post[11];
$volume = $post[12];
$ratio = $post[13];



echo "$selskap</br>";
echo "$ticket</br>";
echo "$siste</br>";
echo "$kejop</br>";
echo "$slag</br>";
echo "$ending</br>";
echo "$ending2</br>";
echo "$apring</br>";
echo "$lav</br>";
echo "$hoy</br>";
echo "$forrige</br>";
echo "$volume</br>";
echo "$ratio</br>";


}

echo "<p>" . count($posts) . " posts found</p>";
```

Comment: Please show examples of data you're trying to "scrape" by copying parts of it here (and not using external link). And please show the PHP-code you have mentioned.

Comment: In left side menu of this link, select 'kursliste'. It will show the table of content. I want to scrape entire table of data. Eg: first column is "selskap" here need to scrape all the name. similarly entire column of table

Comment: <td class="left"><a href="ppaper.php?paper=ASC.OSE">ABG Sundal Collier...</a></td>                                                                                                        This is the sample of code need to be scrape and the data is "ABG Sundal Collier" . But this tag is inside the div tag

Comment: Please show your PHP code with the regex and `file_get_content()` call.

Comment: I submitted my code above

Answer (score 1):

You could use this library
[PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Also refer to this question : [Extract Information from HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35115626/php-if-condition-and-foreach-inside)

Answer (score 0):

You have at least 1 typo in your regex:

```
<td>(>*?)<\/td>.*?
```

is probably meant to be written as:

```
<td>(.*?)<\/td>.*?
```

Comment: even though error messages come like this                                          Warning: file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server. in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\projects\script.php on line 3

Comment: Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.hegnar.no/netfonds/aksjekurser): failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server. in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\projects\script.php on line 3

Comment: Warning: preg_match_all(): Unknown modifier ' ' in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\projects\script.php on line 27

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\projects\script.php on line 29

0 posts found

Comment: Add `print($html)` before trying to parse it. Also, I would use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) with fake browser headers and cookies instead of `file_get_contents()`.